# Need a good CSS spinners creator. Does anybody know one?

Tags: ajax, css, spinner, loading

Does anyone know good CSS spinners creator online application? I tried to find several and found one only on David Walsh blog. It has only one of those :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://cssload.net - this is exactly what you need. As for GIF as Matthew told you - try http://preloaders.net. It's A LOT better

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be done in css / javascript? I always use gifs for my spinners and I generate them here:

http://www.loadinfo.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Spin.js](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/)? It uses only css/javascript.

Comment: Yeah, tried this one, but I liked the cssload.net more. It uses pure CSS which is exactly what I needed